# Repeating something in python

Tags: python

I am Currently facing the problem of trying to get something to repeat itsself. The code below is for a game, where the user has to locate treasure chests in a grid (like battle ships). The code places **1** random treasure chest in the grid and the user has to find it. (These come under the variable name `treasure_row = random_row(board).......treasure_col = random_col(board)`) however I would want so there is more than just **1** treasure chest that is placed in the grid (e.g 10 or 20)

How would i do this?

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(8):
    board.append(["•"] * 8)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print (" ".join(row))

print ("You have chosen the option to play the game")
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(1, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(1, len(board[0]) - 1)

treasure_row = random_row(board)
treasure_col = random_col(board)

turn = 0
for turn in range(64):
    turn = turn + 1
    guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:"))

    if guess_row == treasure_row and guess_col == treasure_col:
        print ("Congratulations! you have found a treasure chest!")
        break
    else:
        if (guess_row>8) or (guess_col>8):
                print ("Sorry, that isn't on the grid.")
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
                print ("You guessed that one already.")
        else:
            if turn == 64:
                print ("Game Over")
            else:
                print ("Sorry there is no treasure here!")
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
                print  ("Turn", turn + 1)
    # Print (turn + 1) here!
        print_board(board)
```

Comment: Slight indentation issues here, could you perhaps correct them so we don't break your code? For instance `def print_board(board):` is an obvious one.

Comment: You could build a list of `(row, col)` tuples and then use `random.sample` to randomly choose from them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use list comprehensions for quick & oneline expressions.

- create the board
- create the list of possible coords using 1 line an a listcomp, using a list of `tuple` instead of 2 separate lists
- use `random.sample` to be sure to select the correct number of items (with repeated `random.randint` calls, you can hit the same locations: there would be less treasures than expected)
- print the treasure list (so you can test)
- check x & y at once using `in` in the list of treasure tuples

simple proof of concept creating at most 5 treasures:

```
import random

board = [["*"]*8 for _ in range(8)]

possible_coords = [(x+1,y+1) for x in range(len(board[0])) for y in range(len(board))]

treasure_coords = random.sample(possible_coords,5)

print(treasure_coords)

x=int(input("x coord"))
y=int(input("y coord"))

if (x,y) in treasure_coords:
    print("you have found the treasure")
```

examples of treasure locations:

```
[(2, 3), (8, 8), (4, 1), (8, 7), (6, 4)]
[(1, 1), (5, 8), (3, 7), (4, 4), (8, 7)]
```

comments on your code:

- `randint(1, len(board[0]) - 1)` is missing the last element.
- you increase `turn` within the `for` loop increasing `turn` as well.

Comment: Ok i have applied this to the code, and it works! However would there be a way for the program to keep running when the user has found a chest?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is storing the treasure chests via a list of tuples:

```
treasure_chests = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (1, 4)]
```

then comparing the guesses using the `x in y`:

```
if (guess_row, guess_col) in treasure_chests:
```

If you want to generate treasure, I would use a function like this:

```
def generate_treasure(num, max_x, max_y):
    treasure_chests = []
    while len(treasure_chests) < num:
        new_chest = (random.randint(1, max_x), random.randint(1, max_y))
        if new_chest not in treasure_chests:
            treasure_chests.append(new_chest)
    return treasure_chests
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> generate_treasure(5, 10, 10)
[(10, 5), (2, 3), (2, 9), (9, 4), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: @j.don I added how to generate whatever number of treasure chests you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, just create two different `treasure_row`s and `treasure_col`s. Like so:

```
treasure_row_1 = random_row(board)
treasure_col_1 = random_col(board)

treasure_row_2 = random_row(board)
treasure_col_2 = random_col(board)

turn = 0
for turn in range(64):
    turn = turn + 1
    guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:"))

    if guess_row == treasure_row_1 and guess_col == treasure_col_1 or guess_row == treasure_row_2 and guess_col == treasure_col_2:
```

or do this via arrays of tuples. as you see fit

Comment: ok i will try this, as well as the tuples. However wouldn't this code return only 2 chests? Im probably wrong, and i'll give it a try.

Comment: @j.don of course. but what exactly do you want? a random number of chests? a dynamically set number? it all depends.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have a `list` of treasure chest locations `treasure_locations` you check against:

```
#...
def random_col(board):
    return randint(1, len(board[0]) - 1)

treasure_locations = []
   while len(treasure_locations < 10): #Creates 10 locations
      treasure = random_row(board), random_col(board)
      if treasure in treasure_locations: #duplicate, try again
         continue
      treasure_locations.append(treasure)

turn = 0
for turn in range(64):
    if( not treasure_locations ):
       print "You found all the treasure!"
       break
    turn = turn + 1
    guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(input("Guess Col:"))
    guess_loc = guess_row, guess_col
    if guess_loc in treasure_locations:
        print ("Congratulations! you have found a treasure chest!")
        treasure_locations.remove(guess_loc ) #remove once found
        break
    else:
        #...
```

Comment: Ok i shall try this.